# Need Help Overriding CSS a:hover

Tags: css, hover

If you mouse over the Red "Donate" button in this layout, you'll see that the layout wigs out. This is much worse in Chrome & Safari than Firefox.

The link works, but the button shifts to a totally different position on the page because of the CSS on the nav-1 element. I'm not sure how to override this for ONLY the Red button.

http://chadairhart.frmboy.com/

Thanks for any help.
Jason

Comment: Seriously dude? You're asking for help with CSS, and you give us a link to a page that has a *minified CSS file*? You must not be that interested in getting help.

Comment: Can you please post the original pertinent code?  Since the issue is now fixed on your site, this question is no longer useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Navigation Button Breaks in IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448120/navigation-button-breaks-in-ie8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the rule

```
position: absolute !important
```

to

```
<li id="menu-item-521" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-521">
```

Comment: Looks like that fixed it kei! Thanks so much. I've been using this forum for 2 days and have received 2 quick answers. Hats off to the entire community.

Comment: +1 for a fix in a way I didn't think about.

Answer (score 1):

In your stylesheet, remove `position`, `top`, and `left` from

```
#menu-item-521 {
width: 180px;
background: #FE2E0D;
text-align: center;
position: absolute; //REMOVE
top: 0; //REMOVE
right: 0;  //REMOVE
padding: 0;
margin-left:110px; //ADD
}
```

Add

`margin-left:110px;` or thereabouts.  You may want to adjust

Comment: Well, that would fix the a:hover issue, but I want to make sure that the button is pushed to the most top-right position possible. kei's suggestion of adding the !important rule to the position fixed the issue. Thanks though.

Comment: True @Jason.  Adjusting the `margin` would fix that.  But @kei had a great fix.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `float: left` from `#nav-1 li, #nav-2 li` with `display: inline-block;` for file dynamik-min-4.css

Comment: inline-block is poorly supported. Not a good suggestion.

Comment: @stargazer712, Did you try it? As far as I know, IE6 does not support it. Jason, are you supporting IE6?